# Skype: Status message "Last seen days ago"

Tags: skype

I'm using Skype android 8.2.0. Just below the contact name, it writes the last seen time and it worked as it should, up to present.
One hour ago I was talking to a contact, and now the contact is offline and it writes "Last seen days ago".
Does it mean I'm blocked? Or what can be the reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the LastActive attribute in Skype. The solution would be for your contact to sign out and back in.

You can read it all [here.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3056287/lastactive-attribute-provides-inaccurate-information-about-a-user-s-st)